# Allow for a pagebreak in a long code segment (using float/listings)

Tags: listings, page-breaking, code

I have a problem with inserting pieces of code in my thesis. Until now, most codes have been only a few lines and behaved beautifully. However, I also want to display some larger codes (in the appendix) and here, my configuration inserts the code but leaves out anything that exceeds the length of the page. I managed to solve a similar problems with lines which are too long using lstset and breaklines (see my code example), but couldn't find anything similar for this other problem.

I suspect it has something to do whit the "Code"-function being a float.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
    \geometry{a4paper} 
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{verbatim} 
    \usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
    \floatstyle{plain} 
    \newfloat{Code}{H}{myc}

    \lstset{language=R,
      breaklines=true,
    }

    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \mainmatter

    \chapter{Code}

    \begin{Code}
    \centering
    \lstinputlisting[title=\textbf{R-Sourcecode: CodeExample.R}]{./code/CodeExample.R}
    \caption{\label{codelabel}Code to do stuff}
    \end{Code}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Per definition, floats can't be broken over a page. You will need to be more specific about what you're trying to do and why the things one can find on the topic "float pagebreak" don't work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please make your code self contained. As it is now nobody except you can compile it because it requires some external files, we don't have. Please take a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) for some guidelines on how to create an MWE.

Comment: You shouldn't use floats (as @magula already mentioned). To get the caption, you could use KOMA-scripts `\captionof` like so: `\captionof{Code}{Code to do stuff}`

Comment: @Skillmon Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1):

My suggested usage of `\captionof`. Note that you'll have to define more than just `\newfloat` for it to work which is why I used KOMA's `\DeclareNewTOC`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=C,
  breaklines=true,
}

\DeclareNewTOC[% declare new float with the means of KOMA script
    float,% define the floating environments `Code` and `Code*`
    nonfloat,% define the non-floating environment `Code-`
    counterwithin=chapter,% reset the counter with every new chapter
    type=Code,% the name with which commands like the environment name are built
    name=Code,% the name printed in the captions and stuff
    listname={List of Codeblocks},% the name for the toc
  ]{Code}% file extension for toc-file

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

\chapter{Code}

% not using float though it is defined because it won't be page breakable
\rule{\textwidth}{0.7\textheight}

\begin{center}
\captionof{Code}{Based on https://www.xkcd.com/221/\label{codelabel}}
\begin{lstlisting}
int getRandomNumber();
int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  int i;
  i = getRandomNumber();
  return i;
}
int getRandomNumber() {
  return 4; // chosen by fair dice roll.
            // guaranteed to be random.
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result is page breakable and has a caption.